# Calculation of a derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I have to calculate the following derivative
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\Vert x\Vert}}e^{ix\cdot y}$$
Then I write
$$e^{ix\cdot y}=e^{i\Vert x\Vert\Vert y\Vert\cos\alpha}$$
andI derive; is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

We have  $\alpha=\alpha(x,y)=\cos^{-1}\left( \left\langle \frac{1}{\|x\|}\cdot x\,,\, \frac{1}{\|y\|}\cdot y\right\rangle \right) $!
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial{\Vert x\Vert}}e^{i\langle x, y\rangle}
=
&
\frac{\partial}{\partial{\Vert x\Vert}}e^{\left({\|x\|}\cdot i\left\langle \frac{1}{\|x\|}\cdot x\,,\, y\right\rangle\right)}
\\
=
&
e^{{\|x\|}\cdot i\left\langle \frac{1}{\|x\|}\cdot x\,,\, y\right\rangle}
\frac{\partial}{\partial{\Vert x\Vert}}
\left({{\|x\|}\cdot i\left\langle \frac{1}{\|x\|}\cdot x\,,\, y\right\rangle}\right)
\\
=
&
e^{{\|x\|}\cdot i\left\langle \frac{1}{\|x\|}\cdot x\,,\, y\right\rangle}
\left(
{ i\left\langle \frac{1}{\|x\|}\cdot x\,,\, y\right\rangle}
+
{{\|x\|}\cdot i\left\langle \frac{-1}{\|x\|^2}\cdot x\,,\, y\right\rangle}
\right)
\\
=
&
i\frac{1}{\|x\|}e^{ i\left\langle x\,,\, y\right\rangle}
\left(
{ \left\langle  x\,,\, y\right\rangle}
-
{{\|x\|}\cdot \left\langle x\,,\, y\right\rangle}
\right)
\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was E. Costa's purpose but the answer should be: expression $\frac{\partial}{\partial{\Vert x\Vert}}e^{ix\cdot y}$ is ambiguous and then meaningless.

You can find several different answers depending on how you interprete it. And contrary to what suggest nbubis, $||y||$ and $α$ are not necessarily independent from $||x||$. Dependency is a question of choice. I can rewrite $x\cdot y$ in function of a different set of real-valued parameters and declare them independent.

If you rewrite your expression $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{\Vert x\Vert}}e^{ix\cdot y}\right)_{||y||, \alpha}$ using thermodynamicians convention (here subscript "$||y||, \alpha$" means holding $||y||$ and $\alpha$ constants), then the result is actually $i(\Vert y\Vert\cos\alpha )e^{ix\cdot y}$

Comment: In my expression $y$ is a fixed point so its norm is constant. The variable is $x$ and with $x\cdot y$ I mean the scalar product.

Comment: Even by declaring that $y$ is constant your expression is still ambiguous, because this does not imply that the angle must be hold constant (and this is unrelated to the distinct possible meanings of the dot operation). Of course I had guessed what you meant. But this is my point: I had to guess. Because the expression used is an abuse of notation, and not even a conventional one.

Comment: Actually I have to evaluate
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\Vert x\Vert}\Vert x\Vert e^{ix\cdot y}$$.
The angle is not a costant, but I can use the suggestion of Costa.

Comment: If the angle is not constant your question is actually very ambiguous. I don't know what Costa considered to be held constant in his equation (or if he even thought about this issue). But I'm not sure the result is what you want. So you should ask yourself: what do I really mean in this expression.

Comment: I found yhis question in various articles. Maybe they define $\Vert x\Vert$ as a new variable $r$ and so they consider
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} re ^{ix\cdot y}$$

Comment: This would be still ambiguous, because $r$ and $x$ are dependent but not in a bijective way.

Comment: Maybe they consider $r$ and $x$ as two independent variable.

Comment: @Burakumin If I use spherical coordinates? So I have:
$$x\cdot y=|x|y_1\sin\theta\cos\phi+|x|y_2\sin\theta\sin\phi+|x|y_3\cos\theta$$
In this way
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial|x|}e^{ix\cdot y}=i(y_1\sin\theta\cos\phi+y_2\sin\theta\sin\phi+y_3\cos\theta)e^{ix\cdot y}=i\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|}e^{ix\cdot y}$$

Comment: @Math: We have $\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|} = \cos(\alpha) |y|$ so this is exactly the first case you considered: a constant angle. So once again, what is your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Since $||\vec{y}||$ and $\alpha$ are not dependent on $||\vec{x}||$.

Comment: So I have simply
$$i(\Vert y\Vert\cos\alpha )e^{ix\cdot y}$$

Comment: @Math - yes, that's so.